# Propel query with nested statements and empty field value

Tags: join, propel

I have quite a complex SQL query which I would like to transform into Propel but I am not sure about the best approach.

The query I need looks like this:

```sql
SELECT id_loan 
FROM loan loanA
  JOIN loan_funding on fk_loan = loanA.id_loan
  JOIN `user` userA on loan_funding.fk_user = userA.id_user
WHERE 
  userA.`acc_internal_account_id` is not null
  AND loanA.`state` = 'payment_origination'
  AND loanA.id_loan IN (
   SELECT id_loan from loan loanB
   JOIN loan_funding on fk_loan = id_loan
   JOIN `user` userB on loan_funding.fk_user = userB.id_user
   WHERE 
     userB.`acc_internal_account_id` is null
     AND loanB.`state` = 'payment_origination'
     GROUP BY loanB.id_loan
)
GROUP BY loanA.id_loan
LIMIT 1;
```

What I would like to have is something completely based on the Generated Query Methods but I do not quite get how to do it.

Performance is not an issue but as for now it is unclear where and how those queries will be called from. However, it is important to get back an object as we need to use the getters and setters.

I found this website: http://propelorm.org/blog/2011/02/02/how-can-i-write-this-query-using-an-orm-.html which looks really cool and helpful, however, I am not sure what option fits best here.

I do not expect a complete solution but maybe some thoughts how to narrow down the problem...

What confuses me is especially the part where it compares the id_loan and fk_loan before it goes to the user table. How would this relationship be represented by propel? Might it be better to split the whole thing in multiple queries?

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: If you need to hidrate an object, then you will need to get all columns. Also you're not stating your propel version